# Are there any tools to export weblogic statistics to prometheus?

Tags: weblogic, prometheus, grafana, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

Wanted to know if there are any libraries/tools/APIs to export weblogic statistics to prometheus and further to grafana for monitoring purpose.

Answer (score 0):

weblogic-monitoring-exporter from [Oracle's GitHub Repository](https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-monitoring-exporter)

Answer (score 0):

With the older version of the weblogic wlst does provide the metrics. WLST is weblogic scripting tool.

Following things you can do:

1. Connect to wls server with wlst and write data into the file. Could be the log.
2. Use MTAIL tool to get the data (time-series)etc from parsing the log file.

References:

https://github.com/google/mtail

https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/monitor-weblogic-stuck-threads-wlst-script/